# Converting a List of DataFrames to a Tuples, Maintaining DataFrame Structure

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, tuples

After reading in 18 CSV files and appending them all to a list, so that (first two are displayed):

```
In [175] li

Out[175]: 
[   ABC_IncomeStatement_Annual_As_Originally_Reported  ...           TTM
 0                                       Gross Profit  ...   903,400,000
 1                                      Total Revenue  ...   903,400,000
 2                                   Business Revenue  ...   902,700,000
 3                                      Other Revenue  ...           NaN
 4                          Operating Income/Expenses  ...  -280,200,000
 ..                                               ...  ...           ...
 57                                         Basic EPS  ...          2.56
 58                                       Diluted EPS  ...          2.56
 59                                        Basic WASO  ...   193,576,187
 60                                      Diluted WASO  ...   193,576,187
 61                  Fiscal year ends in Jun 30 | AUD  ...           NaN
 
 [62 rows x 12 columns],
    DEF_IncomeStatement_Annual_As_Originally_Reported  ...            TTM
 0                                       Gross Profit  ...  1,321,800,000
 1                                      Total Revenue  ...  1,347,600,000
 2                                   Business Revenue  ...  1,347,600,000
 3                                      Other Revenue  ...            NaN
 4                                    Cost of Revenue  ...    -25,800,000
 ..                                               ...  ...            ...
 63                                         Basic EPS  ...           0.07
 64                                       Diluted EPS  ...           0.07
 65                                        Basic WASO  ...  2,316,707,932
 66                                      Diluted WASO  ...  2,316,707,932
 67                  Fiscal year ends in Dec 31 | AUD  ...            NaN
```

Where len(li) = 18. I have then taken the list of tickers using:

```
tickers = []
for code in range(0,len(li)):
    tickers.append(li[code].columns[0][:3])

['ABC',
 'DEF', 
  etc.]

test_tuple = list(zip(tickers,li))

def tuple_to_dict(tup,di):
for a,b in tup:
    di.setdefault(a,[]).append(b)
return di
```

I have then created a list of tuples

```
di = {}
ASX = tuple_to_dict(test_tuple,di)
```

Now when I call `ASX['ABC']` I am returned with the corresponding data, however it appears in a list object, not a DataFrame, which it was initially in and which I was hoping to keep it as.

Is there a way to maintain the DataFrame structure? There have been similar questions asked, none however related to a list of DataFrames.

Initial read in as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = '/Users/.../.../.../.../...'

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=None,header=0)
li.append(df)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you transform it to tuple and then to a dict. You can just append it to dict like in the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

li = [pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']}),
pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']})]
keys = ["df1", "df2"]

d = {}
for i, k in enumerate(keys):
    d[k] = li[i]
```

Where `print(type(d["df1"]))` returns: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`